# Caching Redis in filter of Gateway service

Tags: java, caching, redis, spring-cloud-gateway

I have gateway service, I need cached get requests from another service. Caching is doing into gateway filter. I can't resolve problem with caching redis. How I can get response body? Class ServerHttpResponse hasn't this method. I use Spring Boot 3.1.1

I tried lots of methods, but can`t get response body

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Are you able cache the response in api gateway. I also have the same requirement. Can you help me if you have any solution

Comment: i give up, but can consult. Use the HandlerInterceptor for the checking cache into redisTemplate. if its not there u go next execute request. and write class which implements ResponseBodyAdvice and into method beforeBodyWrite save the cache )
I hope was useful.
(sorry for my english)